# Scale on the y-axis in a tree rotated with 'layout_dendrogram()' using ggtree

Tags: r, phylogenetics, ggtree

I'm editing a time-scaled tree using ggtree. The dates are correctly adjusted when I apply the 'mrsd' command and 'theme_tree2()', but when I try to rotate the tree with 'layout_dendrogram()', the scale still remains on the x-axis with no dates. Is there a way to place the date scale on the y-axis in a tree rotated with 'layout_dendrogram()'?

```r
# Code without layout_dendrogram()
ggtree(my_tree, mrsd='2022-12-31') %<+% 
  metadato_arbol + 
  geom_tippoint(size = 2) + 
  theme_tree2()
```

[image]

```r
# Using layout_dendrogram()
ggtree(my_tree, mrsd='2022-12-31') %<+% 
  metadato_arbol + 
  geom_tippoint(size = 2) + 
  theme_tree2() + layout_dendrogram()
```

[image]

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this is only a guess, but try substituting `theme_dendrogram()` for `theme_tree2()` and see you still get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following via gridExtra,

```r
library(gridExtra)
library(ggtree)
library(ape)
set.seed(2023-08-23)
my_tree <- rtree(30)
p <- ggtree(my_tree, mrsd='2022-12-31') %<+% 
  metadato_arbol + 
  geom_tippoint(size = 2) + 
  theme_tree2() # + geom_text(aes(label=node))
gridExtra::grid.arrange(p, p %>% rotate(33) %>% rotate(52), ncol=2)
```